# How to set gzip compression on Azure cdn

Tags: azure, compression, azure-cdn

i already set Compression Enabled on azure cdn manage on azure portal
The file link is: 
https://valoreti.azureedge.net/qaenv/scripts/StoresMinified.js?v=1.0.6976.26662

the actual file size is ~450KB
when i make run test on this site 
http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test

it says that the file is not compressed
but when i check at chrome developer tools i see content-encoding: gzip
(also google site speed test shows the same)

so is my file is compressed or not?
if not, how to fix it?

Comment: When I observed the network traffic, I noticed that the underlying blob is not gzip compressed. I am not sure how compression enabling work with Azure CDN but I thought I would share my observation with you. HTH.

Comment: Thasks  Gaurav Mantri